# Java replace content which use whitespace as delimiter in a string(case insensitive)

Tags: java, regex, replace

First, consider the case sensitive.
For example, `str = "foo foo ,foo, .foo. foo foo" ; positions :1  2  3  4  5  6`.

As the second `"foo"` and the fifth `"foo"` use whitespace as delimiter, they will be replaced by `"zoo"`.

Then, the `result = "foo zoo ,foo, .foo. zoo foo"`

Second, consider the case insensitive, for example:

```
str = "foo Foo ,foo, .foo. Foo foo" ; positions :1  2  3  4  5  6
```

As the second `"Foo"` and the fifth `"Foo"` use whitespace as delimiter, they will be replaced by `"zoo"` in a case insensitive scenario.

Then, the `result = "foo zoo ,foo, .foo. zoo foo"`

I would like to use `replaceALL()`, but couldn't find regex can restrict delimiter  on the content. Also, how to combine delimiter restriction with case insensitive restriction?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using replaceAll its a good aproach. I think that you must look for regex, in this [link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_regular_expressions.htm) for example.

This is an implementation that apply for your examples, but maybe you need to make some changes if you want something a bit different.

```
text = text.replaceAll("(?i) " + keyWord + " ", " zoo ");
```

In this case,

```
keyWord = "foo";
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly:

```
    String t = "foo Foo ,foo, .foo. foo foo";
    t = t.replaceAll("(?i)(?<=\\s)(\\w+)(?=\\s)", "zoo");
    System.out.println(t); // foo zoo ,foo, .foo. zoo foo
```

Comment: does this mean if my string has other words like ttt kkk EX: " foo ttt kkk .foo. foo. foo" I can use str = str.replaceAll("(?i)(?<=\\s)"+"foo"+"(?<=\\s)", "zoo" ? thank you!

Comment: @angelionmaker your comment makes no sense to me, could you re-phrase may be?

Answer (score 0):

```
        String str1 = "foo foo ,foo, .foo. foo foo" ;
        String str2 = "foo Foo ,foo, .foo. Foo foo" ; 
        str1 = str1.replaceAll("(?i) foo ", " zoo ");
        str2 = str2.replaceAll("(?i) foo ", " zoo ");
        System.out.println("str1: "+str1);
        System.out.println("str2: "+str2);
```

Comment: Thank you so much!